# Application.Calculation after subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

All my UDF functions have

```
Application.Volatile
```

When I run a subroutine and end with

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.Calculate
```

Is the Application.Calculate not needed when Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default UDFs in Excel are non-volatile. See here: [Volatile functions](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/volatile-functions.html)
They are only recalculated when any of the function's arguments change.

You are forcing a recalculation with the .Calculate thereby making it volatile.

Comment: All my UDFs have .Volatile. So I guess I can throw out .Calculate from my Subs. Thanks for the quick answer.